# Is this the safest way to copy a remote database to development?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am just wondering if this is the safest way, in terms of the database, to copy my production setup to a development environment?

```
ssh user@app.com pg_dump app-production | psql app-development
```

I just want to make sure that this command doesn't or can't have any unintended side effects on the database being dumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will impose a considerable load on the production to read all of the data from disk and send it over the net.  It will also lock each object, sometimes in ways that can potentially interfere with the operation of the production system.

I think the least-impact method is to hook into whatever backup system you already have in place for the production system.  If you use pg_dump for your backup, restore from the most recent one of those without touching production at all.  If you use wal archiving for your backup, "restore" from that to get your clone, again without touching production at all.

Comment: Because of this comment, I ended up going with a solution that created partitioned database backups and stored them in an S3 server. That way, without touching the actual production server, I could just download the latest backup from S3 and restore from that in development. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

It won't make any changes to the production database, however it might have a noticeable effect on production database performance.

It will increase the general load as its obviously going to access all the tables and the large objects.

However, the thing I'd be more concerned about is the way you're using the network.  By piping direct through  the connection you're relying on an open network connection throughout the process of the pg_dump and also keeping the access open until the load is completed at app-development.

Also, if there is a network drop or anything, you'd have to restart completely.

I'd recommend you dump to a file if you can.  Something like

```
pg_dump -Fc --file=app-production.backup app-production
```

And then transfer app-production.backup with sftp to your dev box.

That way you can utilise the custom format "-Fc" which compresses the data so your ssh hit will be smaller.   Also once you sftp the file to your local dev box, you can then load, reload, reload again as often as you want without revisiting your production database.

[PG Dump documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html)